# Capture dynamic data from store EXTjs

Tags: arrays, extjs, push

I want to load data dynamically in a graph.

If my data is:

```
"data": [
    {
        "A": "11",
        "DATE": "2018-02-07",
        "B": "100"
    },
    {
        "A": "12",
        "DATE": "2018-03-04",
        "B": "1"
    }
]`
```

And the view part is

```
loadChart: function () {

var cha = this.down('#charid');
var iii = null;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: utils.createUrl('api', 'dashboard-read'),
        async: true,

        callback: function(opts, success, response) {
            try {
                if (success) {


var fields = ['A', 'B'];

cha.series.clear();
    for(var i=0;i<fields.length;i++){

    cha.series.add({           
    type: 'line',
    axis: 'left',
    xField: 'DATE',
    border: false,
    flex: 1,
    title: fields[i],
    yField: fields[i],      
    markerConfig: {
        radius: 4
    },
```

}

What I need is instead of defining `var fields = ['A', 'B'];` in view have to push the data from the back end to the fields array dynamically. Because the backend may send different companies in different times. So can't hard coded them.

Comment: post your `console.log(response)`

Comment: responseText : 
"{"success":true,"code":0,"error":null,"total":1,"data":[{"DATE":"2018-02-07","A":"10","B":"3"},{"DATE":"2018-03-04","A":"1","B":"5"}]}"

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach:

```
...
callback: function(opts, success, response) {
    if (success) {
        responseText.data.forEach(function(o){
            cha.series.add({           
               type: 'line',
               axis: 'left',
               xField: 'DATE',
               border: false,
               flex: 1,
               title: o.A,
               yField: o.B,      
               markerConfig: {
                   radius: 4
               }
           });
        });
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.I don't want to mention any of the places as 'A', 'B' like that. because those I can get many of them. I just simply want to add the index fields of the console.response (without adding the date field) in an array

Comment: I do want to add [A,B,...] in an array(if there are more have add them as well), which I am getting from console.reponse